# Rust how do I create manually an std::env::Args iterator for testing

Tags: rust

I would like to test a function that takes a `std::env::Args` iterator as argument but without using the command line and providing the arguments with a `Vec`:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["hello".to_string(), "world".to_string()];
    print_iterator(env::args()); // with the command line
    print_iterator( ??? ); // how should I do with v?
}

fn print_iterator(mut args: env::Args) {
    println!("{:?}", args.next());
    println!("{:?}", args.next());
}
```

Comment: If you are doing this to test your CLI app, may I suggest that you use *assert_cmd* for this? Example: https://docs.rs/assert_cmd/latest/assert_cmd/index.html#examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have your function be generic and take anything implementing `IntoIterator` whose items are `String` values.  This will let you pass in anything that can be converted into an `Iterator` of `String`s (including an `Iterator` itself).

This trait is implemented both by `Args` (itself implementing `Iterator`) and by `Vec<String>`.

```
fn print_iterator(args: impl IntoIterator<Item=String>) {
    let mut iter = args.into_iter();
    println!("{:?}", iter.next());
    println!("{:?}", iter.next());
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=37a081af96994bc5b8d9341a93bea0be))

Comment: I guess you've been faster than me writing your answer, well done.

Comment: `Iterator` and `into_iter()` should be enough.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Sure. But `IntoIterator` accepts more values with less work on behalf of the caller, so there's no reason not to accept it when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just rewriting the solution of @cdhowie with the format that I have seen in the Rust book. Not sure if this is more idiomatic or not.

```rust
fn print_iterator<T>(args: T) 
    where T: IntoIterator<Item=String> {
    let mut iter = args.into_iter();
    println!("{:?}", iter.next());
    println!("{:?}", iter.next());
}
```